# "I have button and textview together in listview row", I want to "update the textview value while click the button" in the same row?

Tags: android, listview, button, textview

How can I add get the reference of that `textview` while click the button in the list view row?

**---------------------------------

`TextView`                  `Button`

---------------------------------**

This is the example of my list view.
I have used the View Holder concept to manipulate the `listview` dynamically.
if i click the button, the value of `textview` want to change.

I had tried to change the value of the `texview` values while click the button, but the it updates the last row `textview` value for every button I click.
thanks and regards.

Finally I got the answer following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) v.getParent();
    TextView text=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.qcountHD);
    if (view.inc.getId() == v.getId()) {
        int count = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        text.setText("" + (++count));
    } else if (view.dec.getId() == v.getId()) {
        int count = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        if (!(count == 0)) {
            text.setText("" + (--count));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the support.....

Comment: post your code. i thing you need to create a list of textviews i.. 1 for each row.

Comment: post some code to help you

Comment: See this link. hope it will help.


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385469/listview-with-textview-and-button-rowid-of-the-clicked-button

Comment: finally i got the answer......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer, we can get any of the child reference using the parent layout.
It points the current parent and it's child's while You click the button.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
    TextView text=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.qcountHD);
    TextView product=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.productHD);
    TextView price=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.priceHD);


    Log.d("Current Product ",product.getText().toString());
    Log.d("Current Price ",price.getText().toString());
    Log.d("Current Quantity ",text.getText().toString());

    if (view.inc.getId() == v.getId()) {
        int count = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        text.setText("" + (++count));
    } else if (view.dec.getId() == v.getId()) {
        int count = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        if (!(count == 0)) {
            text.setText("" + (--count));
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you....